# How to make display none the whole <p> tag when <p> tag contain <br>?

Tags: html, css, tags

I want to make `display:none` the whole `<p>` tag when it contains only `<br>` tag
Eg:

```
<p> <br> </p>
```

Can any one post your answer for above question

Comment: I don't think you can do this with CSS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Try with this

$(document).ready(function(){
   $('p').each(function(){
      if($(this).children('br').length > 0){
        $(this).hide();
      }
   })
})
```

or create a function globally. And call it wherever you needed.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    functionName();
})
function functionName(){
    $('p').each(function(){
       if($(this).children('br').length > 0){
         $(this).hide();
       }
   })
}
```

Comment: Note that this is only on page load. If you're changing things dynamically, you'll need a MutationObserver.

Comment: Yes..Or a function can be created and call it wherever needed.

Answer (score 0):

give any class or id to

tag and write jquery:

```
$('.ptag').css('display','none');
```

Comment: Thanks for you reply @mahesh. But we can't able to add a class in p tag because it dynamically loaded content

Answer (score 0):

cant you add style="display: none" property to the

tag and then use js to display or hide the

tag as needed ?